# Are Terran Units cloned? Where do they come from?

Tags: starcraft-series

Unlike the Protoss who teleport in, or the Zerg who hatch from larvae, Terrans come in space ships. Presumably, their command center contains many, many people living inside. But then you can construct a new building and it will magically be full of people (even if all your command center is flying far away on the map over a pit of lava).

Is there supposed to be a logical explanation for this? Or am I thinking too hard about it?

Comment: I created a meta topic for us to discuss the validity of these types of questions: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11043/are-questions-about-a-game-universes-lore-on-topic-on-the-gaming-stack-exchange

Comment: [Blizzard have spoken about Terrans ability to quickly populate, using cloning](http://us.battle.net//sc2/en/blog/7493439).

Comment: @Frank - your 'opinion' is **not what close votes are for** - they are for enforcing community rulings. Downvote questions, downvote answers, argue your case in comments or on meta all you want, but you shouldn't close vote things the community has deemed on topic.

Comment: Voting to leave open as per [When is it appropriate to close a lore question as “not addressed directly through in-universe sources”?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7673/4797)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31393/discussion-on-question-by-bizorke-are-terran-units-cloned-where-do-they-come-fr).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lore wise, Terran units seem to be a mix of [space humans](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/T-280_space_construction_vehicle#Service) and [prisoners](http://starcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Marine#Terran_Confederacy).  Most of the collected lore comes from the books released (As the first StarCraft hinted that most Terran units where criminals but didn't explain it any further) but the [first trailer for StarCraft 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aVtXac6if14) shows the process of a creating a Marine by the way of "releasing" prisoners and putting them into a new prison by the way of a power suit.

Since the release of SC2, the [main site starts to reflect more](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/game/unit/reaper) about the units that are created being prisoners being forced to fight for early release of prison.

This does not explain all the units.  Questions like, "Why are Medics and Ghosts built in the same Barracks with Prisoners" or "Are pilots professionals or prisoners" are not answered as well.  For the most part though, we're lead to believe that every human is a separate/unique individual.*

*. Unique but of course it's all the same unit portrait in-game.

Comment: Actually an even weirder question that arises is why a Dark Archon can mind control an SCV into building a Terran army. This was a pretty well informed answer. At some point I'll have to write a blog about the cloning theory.

Comment: Well, it's because the Mind Controlled SCV creates a CC, but it's warpped just enough so that it's actually a Nexus in disguise!  Those new SCVs? Probes with a human-looking puppet.  The Marines?  Zealots with metal bars that look like rifles. (who also shoot by mentally picking up bullets and firing them) Vultures? well, those are still human but they're too dumb to notice all the protoss around wearing paper-plates for masks. :)

Answer (score 5):

The question has already been answered, but I came across something of interest worth mentioning as a separate answer.

In the original Terran campaign on level 4: The Jacobs Installation, Jim Raynor and his team infiltrate a Terran facility, and at one point activate a "teleportation field" which moves them across the map. This is proof that the Terrans have access to teleportation technology, and would seem to explain (or at the very least provide a plausible explanation for) how it is possible for them to move units between buildings when required.

## HOWEVER

Through snooping around on an [official StarCraft blog](http://us.battle.net//sc2/en/blog/7493439), it has also (quite accidentally) come to my attention that Terrans used cloning technology to populate the Koprulu sector (which could explain how they are able to rapidly produce units).

> "This is an excellent question, and one that has been discussed internally for several years. I've always said that these were four crashed colony ships. So while much of their technology was lost, there were certainly means to ensure a foothold on a new, hostile planet – frozen embryos, frozen fertilized eggs, certainly extensive cloning."

This would also seem to be the only way to explain why a mind-controlled SCV is able to construct buildings that can be used to produce more humans.

Hey - if we can rapidly grow/reincarnate Zerg units (including intelligent ones like Kerrigan or the Cerebrate), why not Terrans?